# translate с помощью onmouseenter

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Необходимо чтобы при нахождении курсора на выезжающем div#rollfile, сам этот же div никуда не мог уехать, и лишь после смещения курсора за его пределы, чтобы он уезжал.
А пока что div#rollfile не уезжает лишь до окончания нахождения курсора на div#file.
В итоге требуется чтобы div#rollfile оставался видимым если курсор находится либо на самом div#rollfile, либо на div#file, в противном случае он должен исчезнуть

```js
(function() {
  var flag2 = true;

  document.getElementById("file").onmouseenter = function() {
    let x = document.getElementById("rollfile").style;
    x.transform = 'translateY(0px)';
  }

  document.getElementById("rollfile").onmouseenter = function() {
    flag2 = false;
  }
  document.getElementById("rollfile").onmouseleave = function() {
    flag2 = true;
  }


  document.getElementById("file").onmouseleave = function() {
    if (flag2 === true) {
      let x = document.getElementById("rollfile").style;
      setTimeout(() => x.transform = 'translateY(-200px)', 200);
    }
  }
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: white;
}

.topmenu {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1ft);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.topmenu div:nth-child(-n+4):hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
}

.file {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 20vw;
}

.rollfile {
  position: fixed;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  height: 10h;
  width: 20vw;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.rollfile div:nth-child(-n+4):hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #00FF03;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topmenu">
    <div class="file" id="file">File</div>
  </div>


  <div class="rollfile" id="rollfile">
    <div class="start" id="start">Start</div>
    <div class="open" id="open">End</div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А допускается изменение HTML ? .rollfile если поставить внутри .topmenu, можно записать наведение сразу для общего topmenu...   (и обойстись простым CSS)

Comment: Чтоб ничего не переделывать глобально, оставь онмаусэнтер на том же элементе, а он мауслив навесь на те, что выезжают. На rollfile.

Comment: ну если прям менять менять минимум, то введите переменную булевскую `IsMenuShow` и в соответствии с ней показывать или скрывать меню

Comment: Почему нельзя использовать для решения Вашей задачи CSS? 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  var flag2 = false;

  document.getElementById("file").onmouseenter = function() {
    let x = document.getElementById("rollfile").style;
    x.transform = 'translateY(0px)';
    flag2 = true;
    //console.log("f ent : " + flag2);
  }

  document.getElementById("rollfile").onmouseenter = function() {
    flag2 = true;
    //console.log("rf ent : " + flag2);
  }
  document.getElementById("rollfile").onmouseleave = function() {
    //flag2 = false; если откоментить то скрываться будет при потери фокуса rollfile
    if (!flag2) { // скрывает если вы выбран пункт меню и покинут фокус
      let x = document.getElementById("rollfile").style;
      setTimeout(() => x.transform = 'translateY(-200px)', 200);
    }
    //console.log("rf lv : " + flag2);
  }


  document.getElementById("file").onmouseleave = function() {
    if (!flag2) {
      let x = document.getElementById("rollfile").style;
      setTimeout(() => x.transform = 'translateY(-200px)', 200);
    }
    //console.log("f lv : " + flag2);
  }
  
  let opt = document.querySelectorAll("#rollfile div");
  
  opt.forEach(function(){
    this.onclick = function(e){
      flag2 = false;
      // скрывает после клика на пункт меню
      //if (!flag2) { // скрывает если вы выбран пункт меню и покинут фокус
      //let x = document.getElementById("rollfile").style;
      //setTimeout(() => x.transform = 'translateY(-200px)', 200);
    }
    
  });
  
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: white;
}

.topmenu {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1ft);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.topmenu div:nth-child(-n+4):hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
}

.file {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 20vw;
}

.rollfile {
  position: fixed;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  height: 10h;
  width: 20vw;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.rollfile div:nth-child(-n+4):hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #00FF03;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topmenu">
    <div class="file" id="file">File</div>
  </div>


  <div class="rollfile" id="rollfile">
    <div class="start" id="start">Start</div>
    <div class="open" id="open">End</div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
  var flag2 = true;

  document.getElementById("file").onmouseenter = function() {
    let x = document.getElementById("rollfile").style;
    x.transform = 'translateY(0px)';
  }

  document.getElementById("rollfile").onmouseleave = function() {
    flag2 = true;
  }

  let ele1 = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

  ele1.forEach(function() {
    this.onclick = function() {
      if (flag2 === true) {
        let x = document.getElementById("rollfile").style;
        setTimeout(() => x.transform = 'translateY(-200px)', 200);
      }
    };
  });
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: white;
}

.topmenu {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1ft);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.topmenu div:nth-child(-n+4):hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
}

.file {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 20vw;
}

.rollfile {
  position: fixed;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  height: 10h;
  width: 20vw;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.rollfile div:nth-child(-n+4):hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #00FF03;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topmenu">
    <div class="file" id="file">File</div>
  </div>


  <div class="rollfile" id="rollfile">
    <div class="option" id="start">Start</div>
    <div class="option" id="open">End</div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы осуществили на onclick сокрытие, чего не совсем я добивался, но при этом оставили переменную под названием флаг, которую я задействовал для сокрытия меню, и как я понимаю в вашем варианте она ни к чему.

Мне все же интересно, почему именно в мое примере система с "флагом" не работает.